# Laravel Eloquent multiple whereHas on relationship where column 'order' is higher than the previous whereHas

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, wherehas

I'm working on a bus route system with stops at certain locations.
The route stops are in a ascending sequence by a 'order' column, as in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.. etc.

These are my tables:

BUS

```
id | operator_id | name 
1  | 1           | The Big Red Bus
```

PLACES (some dummy data just for example)

```
id | name       | slug        | parent_id
1  | Amsterdam  | amsterdam   | 
2  | London     | london      |
3  | Stockholm  | stockholm   |
4  | Helsinki   | helsinki    |
5  | Dam Square | dam-square  | 1
```

ROUTES

```
id | name 
1  | Amsterdam - London 
2  | London - Amsterdam
```

ROUTE_LOCATIONS (LOCATIONS)

```
id | route_id | place_id | order | start | end
1  | 1        | 1        | 1     | 1     | 0
2  | 1        | 2        | 2     | 0     | 0
3  | 1        | 3        | 3     | 0     | 0
4  | 1        | 4        | 4     | 0     | 1
```

User Input
The given user input when I start a search to check if we have any available bus routes is a place slug from the PLACES table.
For example:

- from: london
- to: dam-square

Below is the query what I tried so far, but I am really unsure on how to build a check/join into the actual query to check if the 'order' sequence is ascending. I just can't get my head around it.

```
    $buses = Bus::whereHas('route.locations.place', function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
        $query->where('slug', $from)->where('end', 0);
    })->whereHas('route.locations.place', function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
        $query->where('slug', $to)->where('start', 0);
    })->get();
```

Relationships structure is as follows:

```
BUS hasOne ROUTE

ROUTE belongsToMany BUS

ROUTE hasMany LOCATIONS (ROUTE_LOCATIONS TABLE)
```

I have already tried the following query which works to get available routes, but I really like to do it directly in laravel eloquent with my models, so I can easily use the relationships in my view. I am just unsure on how to go about it.

Below query only works with a place ID instead of a slug, and I really like it to be a slug instead of an ID.

```
$routes = DB::select('SELECT R.id, R.name
FROM route_locations L
INNER JOIN routes R ON R.id = L.route_id
WHERE
L.place_id = "'.$from->id.'" AND
EXISTS (SELECT id FROM route_locations F WHERE L.route_id = F.route_id AND F.order > L.order AND F.place_id = "'.$to->id.'")');
```

Does anyone know if this is possible and how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be rewritten to this one:

```
$busses = Bus::whereHas('route.locations.place', function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
    $query->where('slug', $from)
        ->where('slug', $to)
        ->where('start', 0)
        ->where('end', 0);
        // here should do a check if the 'order' column is higher than the first wherehas
})->get();
```

And it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: But how can I actually check if the 'order' column is higher?

Comment: Show table structure of your tables, I don't know what are you trying to do and where is the `order column.`

Comment: I updated the original question with more details of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Still it's not clear, what is `slug` for example, show all tables not only one.

Comment: I have added the table structure information, I hope it makes more sense now?

Comment: MichalOravec, I updated again with more details on what i'm exactly trying to achieve.